# Removing items from one list another list of Integer type

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I have the following two lists. One is a collection of a class and the other is a collection of Integer.

```
Dim CompanyAll As New List(Of CompDTO) 

Dim CompForTerm As New List(Of Integer)
```

The class CompDTO has a field `ID` and I want to remove all those items from CompanyAll list which has their ID's existing in the CompForTerm collection (it contains some integer values).

Comment: `CompanyAll.RemoveAll(Function(x) CompForTerm.Contains(x.ID))`, something like this, untested.

Comment: Thanks.... It works.... :)

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

You can't edit a list while you iterate over it but what you can do is an old fashion for loop and then remove when its found in this.

```
For x = CompanyAll.Count - 1 to 0 Step -1
    Dim c As CompDTO = CompanyAll(x)

    If ( CompForTerm.Contains(c.ID) ) Then
        CompanyAll.RemoveAt(x)
    End If  
Next
```

Comment: Was about to post same answer.

Comment: Thanks. Your idea might work. But my list will be having more than 10k records. In that case iterating through each list and comparing might have performance issues. Please correct me if I am wrong.....

Comment: Yea this is not the best way to do data comparisons of large things like that.  You should be doing in the database then.

Comment: --CompanyAll.RemoveAll(Function(x) CompForTerm.Contains(x.ID))-- this will work

Comment: @Che the one liner is much cleaner, but both solutions will do very similar things. If you are doing this on entities from a database, you may want to think about a LINQ statement which translates to a SQL query behind the scenes, as it's best for this to happen on the server.